# How to get field value in the Serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-serializer

I want to get **id** value passing in the serializer that is
`id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID')` in the function to get the profile object

**def profile_info(self, obj)**

> But it giving the error **id** is `IntegerField` please pass the int or
>   string

Can Anybody tell me how to get values passed in **id** field thanks.  Down below is my serializer code

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID')
    # print ('dadddaaa ',serializers.data)
    profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField('profile_info')
    username = serializers.CharField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    # Nazir = serializers.CharField()
    # profile = UsersSerializer(Profile.objects.get(User.objects.get(pk=serializers.data['id'])))
    def profile_info(self, obj): 
        # print ('selffff   ', serializers)
        prof_obj = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(pk=id))
        return {'id':prof_obj.id}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between User and Profile - OneToOne or OneToMany (FK)  ?? can you add your models here ? if you are using Django Rest Framework, then you need a nested serializer.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for an answer but none of the worked for me but i got it from django it self

you can get it by using initial_data as inital_data returns the query dictionary

```
self.initial_data['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

In Django Rest Framework every serializer extends from the upper class Field so to obtain a value, you most call to_internal_value or to_representation. This process runs automatically on your serializer over each field when you call .is_valid. In your case because you need the value of one Field the best option is skip this process and access using:

```
self.initial_data.get("your field name")
```

This return the original value passed to the serializer without validate. If you know that the function profile_info will be called after run a serializer.is_valid i recommend to access the value using:

```
self.validated_data.get("your field name")
```

Always use .get to get a value in a dictionary because by default returns None in the case that key does not exist. Using brackets will be raise an exception in the same escenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend retrieving the related Profile model with a SerializerMethod, because this will fire a separate query for each User. I suggest to use a [nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for the Profile model, so Django/DRF will build a JOIN query. Also, you don't have to specify each field, you can use the `fields` option of the `Meta` class.

First, make sure that you specify a `related_name` for the user-relation in your `Profile` model, so it will be accessible as a field in the ModelSerializer:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='profile',
)
```

Then create a Serializer for each model:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'ship', 'copilot')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'profile', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

This will give you a JSON like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "profile": {
        "id": 1,
        "ship": "Millennium Falcon",
        "copilot": "Chewbacca"
    },
    "username": "hsolo",
    "first_name": "Han",
    "last_name": "Solo"
}
```

Note: By default nested relations are not writable, but it can be done [by creating your own create() and update() functions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are passing an `IntegerField` object as an id in this query:

```py
Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(pk=id))
```

Try this instead:

```py
Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(pk=obj.id))
```

Full example:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID')
    # print ('dadddaaa ',serializers.data)
    profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField('profile_info')
    username = serializers.CharField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    # Nazir = serializers.CharField()
    # profile = UsersSerializer(Profile.objects.get(User.objects.get(pk=serializers.data['id'])))
    def profile_info(self, obj): 
        # print ('selffff   ', serializers)
        prof_obj = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(pk=obj.id))
        return {'id':prof_obj.id}
```